# assigning n amount of natural numbers to an array

Tags: c++, arrays

so I have a code that prints all the prime numbers between 1 and an upper bound, the problem is I have to manually type all the numbers from 1 to that upper bound(in this case its 10) while storing them in 2 1D arrays

**is there shortcut to store n amount of natural numbers in the array without typing all of them?**

*this is just part of the code where I initialize the 2 arrays*

```
**int numbers1[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};`
**int numbers2[10] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};`
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. The best we get is [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) and some groovy [template meta-programming tricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming#Static_Table_Generation).

Comment: Cheap hack: `int numbers1[10]={ #include<data.csv> };` and generate the contents of the array in your preferred spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota). Also consider to use a `std::vector` instead of the c-array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int x[10];
    std::iota(std::begin(x),std::end(x),1);
    for (const auto& e : x) std::cout << e << " ";

    std::vector<int> y(10);
    std::iota(std::begin(y),std::end(y),1);
    for (const auto& e : y) std::cout << e << " ";
}
```